# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "https:/my url/api/login/" does not contain "{username}". (parameter #1)

Tags: java, android, django-rest-framework, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new in android studio, and i am doing login activity using java, retrofit and web api (django restframework). i am getting this error, **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "https:// my url /api/login/" does not contain "{username}". (parameter #1)
for method UserService.login** , why i am getting this error? eventhough my web api is working?

this is my post data

[image]

this is my LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText edtUsername;
    EditText edtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUsername);
        edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        userService = ApiUtils.getUserService();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
                String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
                //validate form
                if(validateLogin(username, password)){
                    //do login
                    doLogin(username, password);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password){
        if(username == null || username.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Username is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        if(password == null || password.trim().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void doLogin(final String username,final String password){
        Call call = userService.login(username,password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    ResObj resObj = (ResObj) response.body();
                    if(resObj.getMessage().equals("true")){
                        //login start main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DestinationListActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("username", username);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my UserService

```
public interface UserService {
    @POST("https:// my url /api/login/")
    Call login(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);

}
```

this is my RetrofitClient

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

my ResObj

```
public class ResObj {
    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

my ApiUtils

```
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https:// my url /";

    public static UserService getUserService(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

this is my full error I receive

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.smartherd.globofly, PID: 27242
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL "https:// my url /api/login/" does not contain "{username}". (parameter #1)
        for method UserService.login
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:52)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:42)
        at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:61)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.validatePathName(RequestFactory.java:732)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:375)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:295)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:182)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:65)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:25)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:168)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy3.login(Unknown Source)
        at com.smartherd.globofly.activities.LoginActivity.doLogin(LoginActivity.java:64)
        at com.smartherd.globofly.activities.LoginActivity.access$100(LoginActivity.java:20)
        at com.smartherd.globofly.activities.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27242 SIG: 9
```

Comment: why do you think username and password should be on the path ?

Comment: i follow the documentation in ""  https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/02/build-an-android-application-for-user-login-using-restful-web-services-with-retrofit-2-android-tutorial.html ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

For `@POST` type of requests, you can also use `@Field` to pass individual fields of form-encoded request.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("https://www.url.com/api/login/")
Call login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

Documentation of [`@Field`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html) with examples.

#### To process the response:

Define a simple class `AuthenticationResponse`:

```
public class AuthenticationResponse {
    public String token;
}
```

And use it as a generic type parameter of your `login` call:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("https://www.url.com/api/login/")
Call<AuthenticationResponse> login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
```

Using `AuthenticationResponse` will require an update of your `LoginActivity` method `doLogin`:

```
private void doLogin(final String username, final String password) {
    Call<AuthenticationResponse> call = userService.login(username, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                AuthenticationResponse authResponse = (AuthenticationResponse) response.body();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authResponse.token)) {
                    //login start main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DestinationListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("username", username);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

---

For `@POST` type of requests if you need your parameters to be part of the request **body** then you must annotate those parameters with `@Body` annotation. But you can you only one `@Body` annotation as the parameter declared with that annotation will define the whole body of a request.

```
@POST("https://www.url.com/api/login/")
Call login(@Body Credentials credentials);
```

Where `Credentials` is a POJO class:

```
class Credentials {
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

Documentation of [`@Body`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Body.html).

#### Why exactly error happens?

When you use `@Path("name")` annotation you must provide a placeholder for that path argument in your URL.

Instead of:

```
@POST("https://www.url.com/api/login/")
Call login(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);
```

Your POST call declaration should look like this, so the Retrofit will know where to place these path arguments:

```
@POST("https://www.url.com/api/login/{username}/{password}")
Call login(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);
```

Documentation of [`@Path`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Path.html) with examples.

Comment: good day sir, i follow what you've said and i receive this error "" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call ""

Comment: mr @Jenea Vranceanu, i tried and analys your answer,  but i encounter this error, """ java.lang.ClassCastException: com.smartherd.globofly.services.UserService$AuthenticationResponse cannot be cast to com.smartherd.globofly.services.ResObj """

Comment: hey mate youre a genius ! thank you so much. it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your login http endpoint expecting, that you're sending the login data (username, password) as urlencoded parameters in the body?
Then try to modify your UserService interface like this:

```java
public class ResObj {
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}

public interface UserService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("https:// my url /api/login/")
    Call<ResObj> login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Comment: hi, good day mr @brckner i tried your answer and i receive this error from my LoginActivity  "" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call ""

Comment: I think you're getting this error, because the Call type must be parameterized. Try Call<Void> login .... I've edited my answer.

Comment: """ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.smartherd.globofly.services.ResObj.getMessage()' on a null object reference """

Comment: Aaah you're returning a token from the endpoint, so your Call can not be parameterized as Void. I've edited my answer. Maybe you have to customize a bit of the other code too, because i changed the ResObj Class, so Gson can parse the response automatically. If it will still not work, maybe try to identify which data you're expecting on the http endpoint and read a bit in the [retrofit documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) how to send it properly.